# Index of nested list

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

How can I get the index from a gameobject in a nested list?

```
List<List<GameObject>> gpl = new List<List<GameObject>>();
List<GameObject> cbl ;
c = new gameObject("cube1");
cbl.Add(c);
gpl.Add(cbl);
Debug.Log(gpl.IndexOf(c);
```

Comment: Well which index? The index in the outer list, or the index in the inner list?

Comment: The answer to finding the index of a `GameObject` in a `List<List<GameObject>>` would have to be two numbers, the index of the list that contains the object, and also the index of the GameObject within that inner list. Approaching it like your last line isn't going to work.

Comment: I would like to get both index, the outer list and the inner list

Answer (score 0):

If you only have access to `c` you need to search for `cbl` first

```
var gameIndex = gpl.FirstOrDefault(cbl => cbl.Contains(c))?.IndexOf(c);
```

Example with older C# syntax:

```
var cbl = gpl.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Contains(c));
if (cbl != null)
{
     var gameIndex = cbl.IndexOf(c);
}
```

Comment: I only have access to c from a raycast.

when I past your line:
var gameIndex = gpl.FirstOrDefault(cbl => cbl.Contains(c))?.IndexOf(c);
it gives me an "Unexpected symbol `.' " error

Comment: Updated answer with older C# syntax, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly get the index of 'c' in gpl. This is because 'c' is of type `GameObject` while each element within gpl is a `List<GameObject>`.

So your task gets divided into two parts:
1) Get index of 'c' within cbl
2) Get index of cbl within gpl

Here is some sample code:

```
List<List<GameObject>> gpl = new List<List<GameObject>>();
List<GameObject> cbl = new List<GameObject>();
GameObject c = new GameObject();
cbl.Add(c);
gpl.Add(cbl);

Debug.WriteLine(cbl.IndexOf(c));
Debug.WriteLine(gpl.IndexOf(cbl));
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Linq and return a `IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>>` that holds all the indexes (outer and inner) inside the lists where the inner list contains your value (`c`).

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> indexes = 
   gpl.Select((games, i) => new {games, i})
      .Where(arg => arg.games.IndexOf(c) > -1)
      .Select(arg => Tuple.Create(arg.i, arg.games.IndexOf(c)));
```